# Android sound playback delayed until while loop ends

Tags: android, multithreading, soundpool

I have this android issue that has been giving me a hard time.

I'm working on an app where I'm playing a sound whenever the phone senses noise via the microphone. The meat of the logic is a while loop that calls a sound-playing method from another class.

This loop is terminated when a setting method switches the loop's condition to `false`. The problem arises where the playback is delayed until the loop's condition is set to `false`. Once the loop ends, it plays back the calls to the sound-playing method all at once in a messy blast instead of when it was called in each pass of the loop.

This still happens despite threading it and sticking the sound-playing method call inside a `runOnUiThread`. This also happens with MediaPlayer and `SoundPool`. I just want the `playFart()` method to play exactly when it is called.

NoiseActivatedFart

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NoiseActivatedFart extends Activity {

    public static int raw = 0; //For debugging. Will be removed
    public static int trigger = 0; //For debugging. Will be removed
    private Animation press;
    private boolean activate_button_state = true;
    private EvaluateAmbientNoise evaluateAmbientNoise = new EvaluateAmbientNoise(this);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.noise_activated_fart);

        final TextView debugTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.debug);
        press = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.press);
        final ImageButton activateButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.activateButton);

        activateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (activate_button_state) {
                    activateButton.startAnimation(press);
                    activate_button_state = false;

                    //The Android.MediaRecorder documentation recommends that objects
                    //be used in their own threads, as it can really drag the main thread down

                    new Thread() {
                        public void run(){
                            evaluateAmbientNoise.startListening();
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
                else {
                    activateButton.startAnimation(press);
                    debugTextView.setText(raw + " " + trigger);
                    activate_button_state = true;
                    evaluateAmbientNoise.stopListening();
                    System.out.println("stop listening");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Evaluate Ambient Noise

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.app.Activity;

class EvaluateAmbientNoise implements Runnable {

    Activity activity = new Activity();
    int[] average = new int[10];
    int averageNoiseLevel = 1;
    int noiseTriggerLevel = 1;
    Context context;
    FartPlayer fartplayer = new FartPlayer();
    MediaRecorder recorder = null;
    boolean recorder_state = false;
    boolean keepGoing = false;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * The SoundPool object that is utilized by "fartPlayer"
     * requires a context object to function, and gets it from here
     */
    EvaluateAmbientNoise(Context input_context) {
        context = input_context;
    }

    public void run() {
        startListening();
    }

    /**
     * startListening prepares and starts an Android.MediaRecorder object that is
     * used for it's getMaxAmplitude() function. It checks the level of
     * noise several times, averages them, and uses the average to determine a trigger level.
     * It continues to check the levels and play a fart whenever the levels exceed the trigger.
     * It continues until stopListening is called.
     */

    public void startListening() {
        prepareMediaRecorder();
        startMediaRecorder();
        fartplayer.initSounds(context);

        //Gather sound levels, average them, and use it to make a trigger
        averageNoiseLevel = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
            average[counter] = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            System.out.println("getting values: " + average[counter]);
        }
        for (int i:average){
            averageNoiseLevel += i;
            System.out.println("averaging array: " + averageNoiseLevel);
        }
        averageNoiseLevel = averageNoiseLevel / average.length;
        noiseTriggerLevel = (int)(averageNoiseLevel * 1.5);

        System.out.println("average total : " + averageNoiseLevel);
        System.out.println("trigger: " + noiseTriggerLevel);

        //Listen for noise, and play a fart when the noise exceeds the trigger
        keepGoing = true;

        int currentLevel = 0;
        while (keepGoing) {
            currentLevel = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            if (currentLevel > (noiseTriggerLevel)) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        fartplayer.playFart();
                    }
                });
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            System.out.println("tick");
        }
    }

    public static void sleep() {
        System.out.println("sleeping 1000ms");
    }

    // Stops "startListening()"
    public void stopListening() {
        keepGoing = false;
        stopMediaRecorder();
    }

    /**
     * start and stopMediaRecorder essentially staples a crude state flag to an
     * Android.MediaRecorder object. This is needed because of the object's different states,
     * and its simultaneous lack of state-checking functions.
     */
    private void startMediaRecorder() {
        if (recorder_state == false) {
            recorder.start();
            recorder_state = true;
        }
    }

    private void stopMediaRecorder() {
        if (recorder_state == true) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
            recorder_state = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * prepareMediaRecorder initializes the Android.MediaRecorder object before use.
     * Any calls to MediaRecorder throw an exception otherwise
     */
    public void prepareMediaRecorder() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null/");

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Fart Player

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class FartPlayer extends Activity {

    private final Random fartSelector = new Random();
    private List<Integer> fartList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    SoundPool sp;

    //Initializes the SoundPool object and loads some fart mp3s into it
    public void initSounds(Context c) {
        sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart1, 1));
        fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart2, 1));
        fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart3, 1));
        fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart4, 1));
        fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart5, 1));
        fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart6, 1));
    }

    //Plays a random fart from the SoundPool when called
    public void playFart() {
        sp.play(fartList.get(fartSelector.nextInt(fartList.size())),1f,1f,1,0,1f);
        System.out.println("farting");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
public void initSounds(Context c) {
    sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart1, 1));
    fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart2, 1));
    fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart3, 1));
    fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart4, 1));
    fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart5, 1));
    fartList.add(sp.load(c, R.raw.fart6, 1));
}
```

It loads all the sounds at once and once it is played, every single sound is played at once due to every sound being loaded and played at once. You could try using MediaPlayer:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class FartPlayer {

    private Random fartSelector = new Random();
    private List<Integer> songs;
    Context c;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    //Initializes the SoundPool object and loads some fart mp3s into it
    public void initSounds(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        songs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        songs.add(0, fart1);//starts at 0 so random isnt messed up
        songs.add(1, fart2);
        songs.add(2, fart3);
        songs.add(3, fart4);
        songs.add(4, fart5);
        songs.add(5, fart6);
    }

    //Plays a random fart from the SoundPool when called
    public void playFart(){
        int song;
        song = songs.get(fartSelector.nextInt(songs.size()));//selects a random number from 0-5(up to 6)
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(c, song);//sets up the output
        mp.start();//plays
        System.out.println("farting");
    }


}
```

However, it can be solved by loading in one sound:

```
Random r = new Random();
public void initSounds(Context c) {
    this.c = c;
    sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    songs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    songs.add(0, fart1);//starts at 0 so random isnt messed up
    songs.add(1, fart2);
    songs.add(2, fart3);
    songs.add(3, fart4);
    songs.add(4, fart5);
    songs.add(5, fart6);
}

//Plays a random fart from the SoundPool when called
public void playFart(){
    int song;
    song = songs.get(fartSelector.nextInt(songs.size()));//selects a random number from 0-5(up to 6)
    sp.load(c, song, 1);//if this doesnt work, comment this answer
    sp.play(fartList.get(r.nextInt(fartList.size())));
    System.out.println("farting");
}
```